# Adding SMTP header to message sent with JMail

Tags: emails, jmail, smtp

I'm using an e-mail provider (sparkpost) for sending mail from my Joomla! website. Some mails are marketing e-mails others are transactional e-mails.

The default e-mail setting in sparkpost is 'marketing'. There is an option to overrule this: add a SMTP header to the e-mail which states the e-mail is transactional.

I'm sending mail with the JMail class. I'd like to add this extra sparkpost header named X-MSYS-API to e-mails, which can contain params as JSON data.

The option to add to the header is option.transactional:false

```
X-MSYS-API: {
  "campaign_id": "my_campaign",
  "metadata" : {
    "has_pets": true,
    "pet_name": "Spot"
  },
  "cc": [
    { "email": "cc_recip_1@gmail.com", "name": "CC 1" },
    { "email": "cc_recip_2@gmail.com", "name": "CC 2" }
  ],
  "bcc": [
    { "email": "bcc_recip_1@gmail.com", "name": "BCC 1" }
    { "email": "bcc_recip_2@gmail.com", "name": "BCC 2" }
  ],
  "archive": [
    { "email": "archive_recip_1@gmail.com", "name": "Archive 1" }
    { "email": "archive_recip_2@gmail.com", "name": "Archive 2" }
  ],
  "tags": [
    "cat",
    "dog"
  ],
  "options" : {
    "open_tracking": false,
    "click_tracking": false,
    "transactional": false,
    "sandbox": false,
    "skip_suppression": false,
    "ip_pool": "sp_shared",
    "inline_css": false
  }
}
```

Does JMail support adding a SMTP header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I've found it: AddCustomHeader(). Output looks OK like this:

```
$body = "Some content";
$mail = JFactory::getMailer();
$mail->addRecipient("recipient@example.com");
$mail->setBody($body);
$mail->setSender(array("sender@example.com", "John Doe"));
$mail->setSubject("My Subject");
$data = array(
"options" => array("transactional" => "true")
);
$options = json_encode( $data );
$mail->AddCustomHeader("X-MSYS-API", $options);
$mail->Send();
```